# doubt in join -sql

Tags: mysql, join

This query give me an error in

```
JOIN employer_has_worker H, employer E
```

How i can fix this?

```
SELECT id_user, email, 
S.age, 
E.employer
FROM
users U

JOIN single_user S
on S.users_id_user = U.id_user

JOIN employer_has_worker H, employer E // problem here
on H.employer_id_employer = E.id_employer
```

thanks

Comment: It would help if you also gave us the error message that you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a separate JOIN clause for each table you want to join. From your example I'm unable to deduce the relationship between your "users" table and the "employer_has_worker" or  "employer" tables.